# How do I animate background image size on hover smoothly in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image. On hover, I want the image to zoom in slightly. I have it working (see fiddle) but I want it to animate smoothly over 0.3 seconds and then go back smoothly instead of jumping.

How do I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/ufgnroor/2/

HTML

```
                <div class="portfolio-item">

                </div>
```

CSS

```
.portfolio-item {
height: 300px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url('http://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2014/08/08/878/n/1922507/caef16ec354ca23b_thumb_temp_cover_file32304521407524949.xxxlarge/i/Funny-Cat-GIFs.jpg');
}

.portfolio-item:hover {
background-size: 150%;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Transform scale. You will need a wrapper too so the image dosent overflow

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
    </div>
</div>

.portfolio-item:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y0yu9gtx/)

Comment: This makes the whole div scale , I only want to scale the background image inside, and keep the div the same size . So it looks as though its zooming in on the background

Comment: @user3589485 -- yeah i saw that, you simply need a wrapper. see udpated Ans.  nice cat by the way :))

Comment: The main point : You will need a wrapper. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 11):

For your case you have to set the background-size & the transition before the hover:

```
.portfolio-item {
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.portfolio-item:hover {
    background-size: 150%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gv5pjqok/1/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using background-size: 150% use transform. Here's an example:

`.portfolio-item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 2s ease-in;
}`